# WSDL Editor with WS-Security support

Tags: soap, wsdl, ws-security

I have to edit a WSDL to add Policy to sign and encrypt the body. I have been searching for an editor that can help simplify this and cannot find any.

I tried XMLSpy(2008) and Eclipse but there is no security policy support. Have also tried searching the web for and editor with such support with no luck.

So far have resorted to manually editing the wsdl but am curious to find out if there is a tool to assist for future's sake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With security you have to add manually. Havent found an editor that has this built in. This is not to say it will not be widely available in the future

Comment: Is this a separate account from the same person as the question asker?